# XY Plot on image with origin at center

Tags: java, image, netbeans, graphics, linechart

I have a jframe with a background image on jpanel. I want to plot a XY Chart on this image with origin at center of jframe. please suggest me some to proceed on it. I am new to graphics. I am not getting how to proceed.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [`Graphics2D#translate(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#translate-int-int-)
to adjust the origin of your drawing area if that is what you are asking for.

Comment: I want to ask - is it possible to plot xy line chart over image. I found examples of plotting without image. My application needs to plot xy line chart on image.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12883153)

Comment: @DavidPostill The link is documentation; all it needs is some formatting (i.e. `[\`Graphics2D#translate(int, int)\`](link)`) to be an answer. In the future, please [edit] posts like this rather than recommending deletion.

Comment: @Deepak You can get a graphics context (Graphics2D) from an image too and then you can paint on the image like you would paint on anything else.